# angular how to convert url query params into the ui-router query parameters

Tags: angularjs, url-rewriting, angular-ui-router, url-routing

for example i have a URL like this:
`http://localhost:2422/?token=lfTdA5xRaWB6ZZFD7iEZlnAqrFy4FhzXQ==#/`

and i want it to be like so:
`http://localhost:2422/#/token=lfTdA5xRaWB6ZZFD7iEZlnAqrFy4FhzXQ==`
OR:
`http://localhost:2422/#/lfTdA5xRaWB6ZZFD7iEZlnAqrFy4FhzXQ==`

Comment: If it was angular application then query params always seperated with `/` only not with `?`

Comment: its an angular app, but its a link sent to a user by mail, to reset the password

Comment: So, you can create the link in your controller which is supported by the angular.

Comment: yes, as i did now, but the question is still standing,
i know i can be done because i did it in the past in angular 1.2, but i cant remember how

Comment: @galrave i think what you are looking for is **$stateParams** . if the route is `/abc/:parameter` then you can access the parameter by `$stateParams.parameter`

Comment: no, i know how to use the `$stateParams`, what I was looking for a way to convert the regolar url frame into the `$stateParams` frame,